# Removing both html tags and html entities?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I got a string coming from api like this.

```
<p>Be prepared before getting on top of the maountain. Check your speed before rumbling over the wet armored section that make a tight right hand turn into a bridge. This trail is known for its flow. Butcher Ranch is the main trail for the classic Downieville Downhill. Use some caution in the corners here. Watch that you don&#39;t overshoot the switchback to stay on the black diamond descent - the blue route is completely overgrown.</p>\n
```

As you can see its got both html tags and html entities.

I can remove the html tags with this line but `.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')`

I don't know how to remove both html entities & tags in 1 line

Comment: do you want  remove or _replace_ the entities?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderanlovestrees replace them, remove them 
As long as I can't see them in the paragraph its fine

Comment: If replacing was the goal: `new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").documentElement.textContent`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are okay with replacing these HTML entities to their corresponding characters, then a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) is the way to go:

```js
const str = `<p>Be prepared before getting on top of the maountain. Check your speed before rumbling over the wet armored section that make a tight right hand turn into a bridge. This trail is known for its flow. Butcher Ranch is the main trail for the classic Downieville Downhill. Use some caution in the corners here. Watch that you don&#39;t overshoot the switchback to stay on the black diamond descent - the blue route is completely overgrown.</p>\n`;
const parsed = new DOMParser()
  .parseFromString( str, "text/html" )
  .documentElement.textContent;

console.log( parsed );
```